# Open new instance of a form based on data in field of first form

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a data entry form where the data clerk enters client ID among other things. Client ID's are unique to each client. I am currently trapping for duplicate ID's and allowing the clerk to go to the search form and seach for the duplicate ID to verify that it is indeed the same person and not an error inputting data. I would rather open a new instance of the data entry form based on the client ID inputted into the data entry form. I can open a new instance but am not sure how to make it display the client data based on the client ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to do this except to just turn off the screen painting. Here's some code from one of my apps:

```
    Dim frm As Form_frmInventory
    Dim strRecordsource As String
    Dim intType As Integer

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Application.Echo False
    Set frm = New Form_frmInventory
    frm!boxHeader.BackColor = 3276900 ' 5483007
    frm!boxFooter.BackColor = 3276900 ' 5483007
    strRecordsource = "SELECT qryInventoryForm.*, varZLStoNull(IIf([tblInventory].[InventoryClass] In ('BKS','FAC','MTH','MUS','REF','SSC'),[Creator] & [Dates] & OtherAuthors([OtherAuthors]))) AS BibCreator, CreatorDates([Birth],[Death],[OtherAuthors]) AS Dates, varZLStoNull(Trim(nz(UCase([tblBib_Authors].[LastName]) & IIf(Not IsNull([tblBib_Authors].[FirstName]),', ') & [tblBib_Authors].[FirstName],'Anon.'))) AS Creator, tblBib_Authors.CreatorCategories, Nz([CreatorSort],[LastName] & [FirstName]) AS NameSort FROM qryInventoryForm LEFT JOIN tblBib_Authors ON qryInventoryForm.CreatorID = tblBib_Authors.CreatorID WHERE ([quantity]>0 Like getSold()) AND (qryInventoryForm.InventoryID=" & lngInventoryID & ") ORDER BY Nz([CreatorSort],[LastName] & [FirstName]), InventoryClass, ShortTitle;"
    frm.RecordSource = strRecordsource
    ' need to change the caption and disable certain things
    frm.Caption = frm.Caption & " -- " & frm!InventoryClass & "-" & Nz(frm!InventoryNo, Format(frm!InventoryID, "00000"))
    frm!fldShortTitle.SetFocus
    frm!cmbClassFind.Enabled = False
    frm!cmbCreatorFind.Enabled = False
    frm!cmbInventoryNumber.Enabled = False

  [etc.]

    frm.Visible = True
    GoTo exitRoutine

  CloseForm:
    Call CloseForm(Me, True)

  exitRoutine:
    Application.Echo True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Sub
```

The CloseForm() sub is pretty important, as you have to keep track of multiple instances of the form and close the right one. I got the code from the ADH97 and adapted it from there (just the basics).

It would appear from that code (I've forgotten the details) that a form instantiated with `Set frm = New Form_frmInventory` is not visible until you explicitly reveal it. That's a plus, as it should mean that you don't have to turn off the screen (i.e., `Application.Echo False`), but I'm pretty sure that I recall needing it anyway to make things appear smoothly. My memory is that the form would appear with its normal colors and then the background colors would change visibly as the code ran. This means it *was* visible, so I'm not sure why it's necessary to then explicitly set the form visible.

Anyway, that should get you started, I think!